# Run calculation multiple times with different values

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, range, calculation

I have two dictionaries, that look like:

```
dict1 = {1: 10, 2: 23, .... 999: 12}

dict2 = {1: 42, 2: 90, .... 999: 78}
```

I want to perform a simple calculation: Multiply value of `dict1` with value of `dict2` for 1 and 2 each.

The code so far is:

```
dict1[1] * dict2[1]
```

This calculates 10*42, which is exactly what i want.

Now i want to perform this calculation for every index in the dictionary, so for 1 up to 999.

I tried:

```
i = {1,2,3,4,5,6 ... 999}

dict1[i] * dict2[i]
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: the problem here is that you made a wild guess, you've got to put the time in to read the python tutorial. since you asked this might be what you want: list(map(lambda x, y: x * y, [1,2,3], [4,5,6]))

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes i am just getting started, and tried some "learning by doing", guess it will take some time until i am used to the syntax.

Comment: do learn by doing, just make smaller guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a new dict with the results:

```
out = { i: dict1[i] * dict2[i] for i in range(1,1000) }
```

If you need to work with vectors and matrices take a look at the `numpy` module. It has data structures and a huge collection of tools for working with them.